# PHP x64 but max_int isnt larger than on x32

Tags: php, int, 64-bit

been fighting with this problem for a couple of days now, and cant figure it out on my own.

Tried lots of things but none seem to work..

I'm making an mmo and im using bigint's for values as money, now the problem is my php wont recognize integers larger than the PHP_max_int allows obviously, but since im running on x64 it should be a lot bigger than 2147483647, atleast thats what im told

i've got a screenie of the top part of my phpinfo.
have a look: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51136819/phpmaxint.png

any help is appreciated.

If you need more information about the problem, just ask.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So did you install a 64 bit version?

Comment: Not trying to be rude or anything but did you at least take a look at the screenshot i posted? if you did, you could see i have the proper versions installed. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://windows.php.net

x86_64 Builds

> The x64 builds of PHP for Windows should be considered experimental,
>   and do not yet provide 64-bit integer or large file support. Please
>   see this post for work ongoing to improve these builds.

See http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=137002754604365&w=2

Comment: Ahh i see, must have missed that! Thanks for the fast response!
back to debian it is.